# Python : JSON can't be serialized

Tags: python, json, serialization

I have the following json:

```
{
    u'objectid': u'427912',
    u'fooditems': u'Cold Truck: Hamburger: cheeseburgers: hot dogs: hot sandwiches: cold sandwiches: egg muffins: cup of noodles: corn dogs: canned soup: coffee: hot cocoa: hot tea: gatorade: juice: milk: soda: water: fruits: fruit salad: rice pudding: yogurt: candy bars: chips: cookies: donuts: granola bars: muffins',
    u'facilitytype': u'Truck',
    u'priorpermit': u'1',
    u'location': {
        u'latitude': u'37.730906164188',
        u'needs_recoding': False,
        u'longitude': u'-122.373302577475'
    },
    u'lot': u'008',
    u'cnn': u'7253000',
    u'status': u'APPROVED',
    u'schedule': u'http://bsm.sfdpw.org/PermitsTracker/reports/report.aspx?title=schedule&report=rptSchedule&params=permit=13MFF-0072&ExportPDF=1&Filename=13MFF-0072_schedule.pdf',
    u'locationdescription': u'INNES AVE: EARL ST to ARELIOUS WALKER DR (700 - 799)',
    u'latitude': u'37.7309061503597',
    u'blocklot': u'4644008',
    u'address': u'Assessors Block 4644/Lot008',
    u'approved': u'2013-04-04T08:44:08',
    u'received': u'Mar 15 2013 10:24AM',
    u'applicant': u"Park's Catering",
    u'longitude': u'-122.373302577485',
    u'expirationdate': u'2014-03-15T00:00:00',
    u'permit': u'13MFF-0072',
    u'y': u'2094023.408',
    u'x': u'6019956.89',
    u'_id': ObjectId('52afeb27e8de3f3174110041'),
    u'block': u'4644'
}
```

When I call `json.dumps()` on it, I get the error `raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `ObjectId` here?

Comment: It was the mongo id. I got it working after removing it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are including a `ObjectId()` object in your dictionary.

That object is not serializable without special handling. Either replace it with a primitive value, or provide a function to the `default` parameter to encode such objects for you:

```
def objectid_default(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, ObjectId):
        return str(obj)  # hex string version
    raise TypeError(obj)

json.dumps(d, default=objectid_default)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you've solved the problem in your comments, I'm going to post a solution here for those people who find this question and immediately look for answers.

The issue is that some objects in Python can't be easily serialized into JSON, and `ObjectId` is one of them.  Python tries to convert that object to it's JSON equivalent, but doesn't know how, so it throws an error.  The fix is to ensure that all values you're passed into `json.dumps` can be properly encoded (In this case, removing the cast of `_id` to an `ObjectId` and just passing it as a string).